# why this javascript code return undefined?

Tags: javascript

```js
var treeDataOld = [
   {id: '1', pId: '', name: 'root1', checked: false},
   {id: '2', pId: '', name: 'root2', checked: false},
   {id: '3', pId: '', name: 'root3', checked: true},
   {id: '4', pId: '1', name: 'child', checked: true},
   {id: '5', pId: '4', name: 'child', checked: false},
   {id: '6', pId: '5', name: 'child', checked: false},
   {id: '7', pId: '6', name: 'child', checked: false},
   {id: '8', pId: '7', name: 'child', checked: true},
   {id: '9', pId: '8', name: 'child', checked: false},
  ];

function findRoot(node) {
    var getParentNode = function (node, refArray) {
        var len = refArray.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (refArray[i].id === node) {
                return refArray[i];
            }
        }
    };

    if (node.pId !== '') {
        findRoot(getParentNode(node.pId, treeDataOld));
    } else { 
        console.log(node);   // I got OBJECT here
        return node;
    }
}

var rootNode = findRoot(treeDataOld[8]);
console.log(rootNode);   // here is UNDEFINED
```

I want to find the root node by giving a parent node. I got correct result at first console inside function `findRoot` before return. But the console outside the function get UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `findRoot()` function does not return anything after making the first recursive call. What you want is the following:

```
if (node.pId !== '') {
    return findRoot(getParentNode(node.pId, treeDataOld));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using recursive call, but you don't return anything, maybe this is the cause, try to put return before the `findRoot(getParentNode(node.pId, treeDataOld));` and than you have this `return findRoot(getParentNode(node.pId, treeDataOld));`

```js
var treeDataOld = [
   {id: '1', pId: '', name: 'root1', checked: false},
   {id: '2', pId: '', name: 'root2', checked: false},
   {id: '3', pId: '', name: 'root3', checked: true},
   {id: '4', pId: '1', name: 'child', checked: true},
   {id: '5', pId: '4', name: 'child', checked: false},
   {id: '6', pId: '5', name: 'child', checked: false},
   {id: '7', pId: '6', name: 'child', checked: false},
   {id: '8', pId: '7', name: 'child', checked: true},
   {id: '9', pId: '8', name: 'child', checked: false},
  ];

  function findRoot(node) {
   var getParentNode = function (node, refArray) {
    var len = refArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     if (refArray[i].id === node) {
      return refArray[i];
     }
    }
   };

   if (node.pId !== '') {
    return findRoot(getParentNode(node.pId, treeDataOld));
   } else {
    console.log(node);   // I got OBJECT here
    return node;
   }
  }

  var rootNode = findRoot(treeDataOld[8]);
  console.log(rootNode);   // here is UNDEFINED
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem can be solved by returning the value from `findRoot` as other answers have suggested. However, your code can be made more legible (and less susceptible to bugs such as the one you ran into) by simplifying it as:

```
function findRoot(node) {
  var findParentNode = (id, refArray) => refArray.find(node => node.id === id);
  var pId = node.pId;

  return !pId ? node : findRoot(findParentNode(pId, treeDataOld));
}
```

Now, the classic recursion pattern--check for base case, then recursive case--is clearly visible.

We're using `Array#find` here to factor out the basic lookup logic so it does not clutter up your algorithm. If you don't have `Array#find` available, use a polyfill or write your own.

We're also using arrow functions--if you don't have those available, rewrite using standard function notation.

If you want to refactor further, you could write a lower-level `findByProp` to find a particular array element based on the value of one of its properties:

```
function findByProp(array, prop, value) {
  return array.find(elt => elt[prop] === value);
}
```

Now you can write this as

```
function findRoot(node) {
  var findParentNode = (value, array) => findByProp(array, 'id', value);
  var pId = node.pId;

  return !pId ? node: findRoot(findParentNode(pId, treeDataOld));
}
```

Or if you prefer one-liners

```
function findRoot(node) {
  return !node.pId ? node : findRoot(findByProp(treeDataOld, 'id', node.pId));
}
```